# How to write a Polymer3 Mixin in Typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, polymer-3.x

If I try to write a polymer3 mixin which has own Properties in Typescript,
it will fail with the following error:

> xxx incorrectly extends yyy
>
> type of properties are incompatible

I've done like [this](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#defining-mixins) (but in Typescript)
Is there a way to solve without a ts-ignore?

Example Code:

```
function VisuElement<B extends Constructor<any>>(base: B) {
    return class extends base {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super();
            this._ve = true;
            this._veBindings = [];
        }

        static get properties() {
            return {
                unbindOnUnload: Boolean //Needed when a Element is created via a Dom repeat
            }
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
class VisuSignalValueDisplay extends VisuElement(PolymerElement) {
    static get template() {
        return html`
        <div></div>
`;
    }

    static get is() { return 'visu-signal-value-display'; }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            signalName: String
        };
    }
}
```